# linking joints in URDF and/or Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to link joints in the robot description? Here is the setup I have in mind:

I have a robot with Ackermann (car-like) steering. Each of the two front wheels yaws about its own asix of rotation, but when one turns, so does the other. Is there any way to describe this sort of relationship between joints? I could set up a node which listens on some topic to which the steering angle is published to and then republish that angle as the angle of each of the two front wheels, but that feels like a hack.

I also want to be able to simulate this robot in Gazebo so any guidance on that front would be appreciated as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9662/linking-joints-in-urdf-and/or-gazebo?/) by [NStiurca](https://answers.ros.org/users/393/nstiurca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2011-04-06

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, directly describing relationships between joints is not possible in the current version of URDF. See this very informative mailinglist thread about [the limitations of URDF](http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20100806.184444.8658d3f6.en.html), and this other one about the [urdf joint mimic tag](http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110106.222554.4ca722a8.en.html).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2